# Doubts about dependency injection and factories

Tags: .net, mvvm, dependency-injection, ioc-container, factory-pattern

I have this question about the use of factories while using dependency injection:

if I have a ViewModel that has to create another one through a Factory, it needs the factory to be injected via ctor, but if the new VM has to do a similar operation, do I have to have one factory to be injected into the other?

This would bring to a chained factory injection into the other.

Is this a good practice?
Personally I don't like it. Is there any better solution?

Comment: One important reason to use a factory is to break the dependency cycle. When ViewModels can depend upon each other, injecting a factory seems like the right solution IMO.

Comment: That sounds fine. However, while factories are going to depend on other factories, that's just the way DI works. Graphs are likely to be deep, but there's nothing to fear: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence Related: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why it would be a problem. The factory can inject itself into the created ViewModel if necessary.